# Best way to combine integer flags using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In java we regularly combine flags via the | operator.

e.g.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | 
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | 
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
);
```

I can't seem to find the equivalent operator in Kotlin. Anyone know a convenient way to combine integer flags in Kotlin?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Just use [`or`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#operations):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
);
```

This may be a little confusing. You can create a little helper extension function `with` (or whatever) to make it more readable:

```
infix fun Int.with(x: Int) = this.or(x)

getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE with
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION with
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
);
```

Comment: Agree on the infix, I've always found ```or``` to be a little bit confusing

Comment: OR makes absolute sense if you are familiar with electronics