# Convert Java assignment expression to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[image]

Recently I converted the Java code into the Kotlin like pushnotification. After the conversion its shown some error and indicate to manually correct those issues.

In Java:

```
.addFlags(notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
```

After the conversion it's shown like

```
.addFlags(notifyDetails!!.flags notifyDetails!!.flags or Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL)
```

Also, it's indicating an error. How do I fix this?

Comment: refer to this answer: [the link describes how to create || in kotlin using with expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005063/4297023) Good luck.

Comment: refer to the link below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005063/4297023 Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't allow you to use assignments such as `|=` as part of an expression. You need to split this into two expressions:

```
notifyDetailsFlags = notifyDetailsFlags or Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

// the beginning of the call
.addFlags(notifyDetailsFlags)
```

Comment: Still i am getting error only...private var notifyDetails: Notification? = null; notifyDetails = notifyDetails or Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
                inapp_btn.addFlags(notifyDetails)

Comment: Please show a larger snippet of your code. You need to fix the nullability, but I can't show you how to do this correctly based on this single line.

Comment: Screen added above